# Easy for beginners

Tags: word, pattern, visual

[image]

Try to solve this!

This is pretty easy but it’s just for beginners like me

Comment: This question is in a YouTube video.

Answer (score 1):

> 'the' appears at the end of the first line AND at the start of the second.

Comment: For a beginner that was pretty fast!

Comment: @jafe; I'd seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_in_the_Spring before.

Comment: You got it correct! Good job!

Comment: @Stella If this is correct, would you mind accepting it? You can do so by clicking the green tick mark next to the answer.